# Error ejecución paquete distribuible Python

Tags: python, modulos, setuptools

Hola buenos días cuando intento ejecutar el paquete distribuible me da un error cuando escribo `***python setup.py sdist***` , como lo puedo solucionar para lo que pueda ejecutar?

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(


    name ="calculosbasicosmatematicos",
    version="1.0",
    description ="Paquete para calculos básicos, suma,resta,multiplicacion",
    author = "Matias",
    author_mail = "informatica@pildorasinformatica.es",
    url ="www.pildorasinformaticas.es",
    packages=["moduloMatematico","moduloMatematico.calculosBasicos"]

)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor edita tu pregunta

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir, el código esta en la imagen ya

Comment: Para entender a que se refiere Christian y lo importante que es que el código esté copy-pasteado en la pregunta (con formato), te recomiendo esta lectura: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869

Comment: ok bueno ahora lo edito entonces

Answer (score 1):

Antes de responderte te comento que ya que en el título pones *"error en ejecución ..."*, adjuntes también en texto en tu pregunta el error que te aparece. Tuve que buscarlo en la terminal en tu imagen.

El error que te aparece indica que no está encontrando el archivo `setup.py` dentro de tu carpeta `Curso Python PildorasInformaticas`, esto sucede porque ese archivo está dentro de la subcarpeta `modulos`. Para ejecutarlo tienes dos opciones:

- Desde la carpeta `Curso Python PildorasInformaticas/`, ejecutas:

```sh
python modulos/setup.py sdist
```

- Desde la subcarpeta `Curso Python PildorasInformaticas/modulos/`, ejecutas:

```sh
python setup.py sdist
```

Otra cosa, te recomiendo que no pongas espacios en los nombres de tus carpetas (ex. `python-pildoras-informaticas`).

Comment: ahí hice lo que me dijiste copie el archivo setup.py dentro de la carpeta  Curso Python PildorasInformaticas pero me da este error ahora error: package directory 'moduloMatematico' does not exist

Comment: Es mejor que ejecutes de alguna de las formas que te expliqué, sin copiar `setup.py` a otra carpeta.